# Xcode shows black screen when launching on iPod Hardware and iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

The App shows a black screen when launched on  Hardware or even a simulator, I dont have a customized launch, I have the default black launch screen and I have tried putting the app on a Jailbroken iPod Touch 4G, 6.1.3

View Controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController * mcp;

@end
```

View Controller.m

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mcp;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://streamer35.eboundservices.com:1935/tv/humtv/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9Ny8zMC8yMDEzIDg6MTI6MzEgUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1odmptUTNGVGxSazd6Mlp6dk91eW5RPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTIw"];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's

mcp = player;

[self.view addSubview: mcp.view];
[mcp play];
}
```

Comment: If you use a debugger, what are the values of `movieURL` and subsequent  variables?

Comment: I didn't Debug and I got the code from this website and edited the URL

Comment: Maybe you should debug those values, so you can learn why it isn't working.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I get 403'd when I try to visit that URL in my browser.

Comment: it is only for Apple Devices

Comment: I tried it the first time on the app and it worked